# Zend Studio 9 error using built-in debugger - mac os 10.8

Tags: php, macos, zend-studio, osx-mountain-lion

I've just upgraded to a new Mac running Mountain Lion (OS 10.8) and I'm having problems getting my fresh install of Zend Studio 9 to debug properly using CLI.

Note that I am trying to run and debug using studio's built-in debugger and am **not** connecting to a remote server. When I try to run a script as a CLI Application, I get the following error:

```
Error launching '[NAME OF FILE]'
The session could not be started.
In order to generate debug information, please make sure the debugger is 
properly configured as a php.ini directive.
```

On my old machine, running Snow Leopard with the same version of Zend Studio, turning on CLI support and running the file worked fine. Again, I am not using an outside version of PHP so should not have to configure php.ini.

I have tried all manner of restarting and reinstalling and still get this error. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured this out. It was an incompatibility with OSX Mountain Lion. When I was able to get the
Zend Studio console to show the actual internal error message, I
found that the same problem existed for Zend Server (which I think
Zend fixed there).

The same problem in Zend Server is described here:
http://www.andrew-kirkpatrick.com/2012/07/apache-not-starting-in-zend-server-with-mac-os-x-10-8-mountain-lion-upgrade/
The command you have to run for Zend Studio instead of Zend Server is
a little different because the internal version of PHP is buried deep
within the Zend Studio file structure. Instead of the one in the link,
it's this:

sudo cp /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib /Applications/Zend\
Studio.app/Contents/Resources/Java/plugins/com.zend.php.debug.debugger.macosx_5.3.18.v20120625/resources/lib/.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I have the same problem you described. But after I sudo cp /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib /Applications/Zend\ Studio.app/Contents/Resources/Java/plugins/com.zend.php.debug.debugger.macosx_5.3.18.v20120625/resources/lib/ , it repeats the same error message.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I did to resolve the problem:

1. Open Zend Studio
2. Run -> Debug Configurations
3. Select your PHP CLI Application (or create a new one)
4. In the PHP Script tab select Alternate PHP
5. Click on Installed PHPs...
6. Click on Add
7. Fill in form

   - Name: Local Zend PHP-CLI
   - Executable Path: /usr/local/zend/bin/php-cli
   - PHP ini file: /usr/local/zend/etc/php.ini
   - SAPI Type: CLI
   - PHP Debugger: Zend Debugger
8. Click on OK
9. Click on OK
10. In the PHP Script tab select: Local Zend PHP-CLI
11. Click on Apply

In my Studio, the Alternate PHP now reads: Local Zend PHP-CLI (Zend 5.3.14 CLI)

The Debug button will now start a real debugging session!

For all new CLI debugging configurations, just select the Alternate PHP: Local Zend PHP-CLI

Comment: Thanks! In the end I found it was an incompatibility with Zend Studio and the new OSX.